# How can I "press enter" or go to the next line in an embed?

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I'm making my help page and I want to list all of the commands and their description. When I tried putting every command and its description into different "" and then going down a line every time. It didn't work. Here's how I tried, any help is appreciated:

````
async def currency(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    em = discord.Embed(title = f":moneybag: Currency Commands",color = discord.Color.green())
    em.add_field(name = "Free",value = "`cook` - Cook some cookies and sell them"
    "`beg` - Beg and get coins"
    "`farm` - Farm *cough cough* and sell the production for coins"
    "`daily` - Get 2500 coins every day"
    "`balance` - Shows you the amount of money you have")
    em.add_field(name = ":star: Premium",value = "Coming Soon")
    await ctx.send(embed = em)```
````

Comment: just do \n inside of the string it creates a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go down a line in a string, we can simply add `\n` inside of it.
Quick example: (I'm not familiar with discord.py so kee in mind `.setDescription()` is a discord.js Embed function)

```
.setDescription('hello!\nI\nlike\ntomatoes\n!!!');
```

The expected outcome should be an embed who's description displays:

```
hello!
I
like
tomatoes
!!!
```